# What does ".==." mean in batch?

Tags: batch-file

It doesn't appear to be a batch [construct](http://symbolhound.com/?q=.%3D%3D.) so here is the [context](https://pastebin.com/gNsLEWJe):

```
 if %1.==. timeout /t 10 &call wscript /e:JScript "%~f0" runas setup &exit &rem : no arguments, run setup elevated
```

Comment: Type `if /?` It is a batch construct. It is also the original of three comparison operator in MSDos. The line is using `.` to test if `%1` is blank, else the line would error.

Comment: @Mark . has to be appended to filenames?

Comment: `==` is the comparison operator. The dots are used on either side to ensure something appears on either side to perform a comparison. The way this is used is a common method of checking for empty strings, but the wrong way. `if /?` can show you better ways.